# UIFont returning nil for custom font

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts

I am trying to use the [Nunito-ExtraBoldItalic](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito?selection.family=Nunito) font for my UILabel.

I followed the steps outlined in tutorials and other answers.

1. Add font to fonts folder. Made sure the target is set to the project.
   [image]
2. Add the entry to plist.
   [image]
3. Made sure the font is shown in build phase/copy bundle resources. It is shown.
   [image]

I am using the following code to create a UIlabel:

```
uiLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 160, height: 50))
let myfont = UIFont(name: "Nunito-ExtraBoldItalic", size: 14)
uiLabel!.font = myfont
uiLabel!.textColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(51/255.0), green: CGFloat(33/255.0), blue: CGFloat(32/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(100.0))
addSubview(uiLabel!)
```

But UIFont returns nil.

Postscript name of font is "Nunito-ExtraBoldItalic".

I also tried running the following:

```
    for familyName:String in UIFont.familyNames {
        print("Family Name: \(familyName)")
        for fontName:String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName) {
            print("--Font Name: \(fontName)")
        }
    }
```

My font is not shown.

The font is visible in storyboard and other areas.

[image]

I tried using the Nunito-ExtraBoldItalic, Nunito-ExtraBold Italic, Nunito-ExtraBold-Italic as names. None worked.

So I am not sure what the problem is.

Comment: If your code to go through all of the font names and family names isn't showing your font then of course no attempt to use the font will work. Double check your entry in Info.plist. Look at the contents of your built ipa file and make sure the ttf file is there and it matches the entry in the Info.plist.

Comment: What's weird is that the font is being picked up in the storyboard editor.

Comment: Aside from importing it to the project, you need to update your Info.plist and include "Fonts provided by application".

Comment: @TheNitram did that already.

Comment: Just because the font appears in Interface Builder does not mean in any way that you have properly setup your iOS app to use the custom font. The two are completely unrelated.

Comment: @rmaddy Okay. But then what step am I missing to get it working?

Comment: Read the very first comment I posted. And update your question showing "proof" you did the 3 steps you list at the start of your question.

Comment: @rmaddy Edited to show screenshots.

Comment: I just tried it and had problem also. Make sure to add check the right "Target Membership" in the File Inspector. That did the trick for me. So add this as 4th step. And if it also help. do a clean build by cmd+option+shift+K

Comment: @TheNitram yes, I did tick the correct target checkbox.

Comment: "My font is not shown." You're installing two different fonts. Does CircularStd appear in the list? This would at least narrow down possible problems.

Comment: @NimaYousefi I am trying to only add Nunito-ExtraBoldItalic. CircularStd already exists in the folder.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but if you are able to correctly add CircularStd to the app, then that means there's a problem with the Nunito-ExtraBoldItalic font or how you're accessing it. If you cannot access CircularStd from your app, then that means you aren't adding fonts to the app correctly. You need to narrow down what the possible problems are.

Comment: The other fonts were already there before I started working on this project. I am able to use them directly without any problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Add the font file to the project.

[image]

2. Add "Fonts provided by application" in Info.plist.

   `<key>UIAppFonts</key>
   <array>
       <string>CarterOne.ttf</string>
   </array>`
3. Make sure the font file is listed in BuildPhase->Copy Bundle Resources.

[image]

4. Make sure the Target Membership is check.

[image]

5. Do a clean build cmd+option+shift+K

Comment: step 3 helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Step 2 helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add the font to the .plist file
Please read the following:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app

Add the font name to this plist key:
"**Fonts provided by applicatio**n"

Comment: Please redo the steps again. I had to do the exact same thing very recently.